# Parameter in bind don't match the number of bind fields?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm using `mysqli` for execute query on db. This is my code:

```
if($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE code = ?"))
{
    $find = "Op";
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $find);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->bind_result($res);
    $stmt->fetch();
    echo "Res => " . $res;
    $stmt->close();
}
```

now the problem is that on this line: `$stmt->bind_param("s", $find);`
I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

NB: `$connection` contains the connection established with the database. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your `bind_param()` is fine. The problem is with `$stmt->bind_result($res);`. Change your `SELECT` statement from `SELECT * FROM ...` to `SELECT column1 FROM ...`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Okay if I set a specific column like `SELECT column_name` working, I guess that in the `bind_result` I should set the exact number of columns that I want to retrieve from the database? And later, iterate on it through a while.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue, including how to do iteration on them.

Comment: @Sandokan See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `bind_param()` method is fine. The problem is with this statement,

```
$stmt->bind_result($res);
```

In the `SELECT` statement you're doing `SELECT * FROM ...` but in the `->bind_result()` method you're trying to bind only one result column with the variable `$res`.

So your `prepare()` statement should be like this:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE code = ?")
```

Later, if you want to loop through it you can do like this:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    // your code
    // echo $res . "<br />";

}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Follow the correct way like this :**

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(2, $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

**In your case it will be like this :**  **Modified**

```
if($stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE code = ?'))
{
    $find = 'Op';
    $stmt->bind_param(1, $find, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute(); 
    // Fetch column data
    // $result = $sth->fetchColumn(2);
    // Fetch all data
    // $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($result);
    // Fetch only some columns data.

    $stmt->bindColumn(2, $cals);

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
      print $cals . "</br>";
    }       
}
```

**Note :**

> You can specify, how many column data you want.

**Example :**

> You have columns like colone, coltwo, colthree, colfour in your table.
>   You write query : select * from tablename. Now you want to show only 2
>   column (colone,colthree), you can use bindcolumn(). You have to use
>   like this : $stmt->bindColumn('colone',
>   $cal1);$stmt->bindColumn('colthree', $cal3);*

Comment: In your *correct way* you didn't address the issue at hand. And no, the problem is not with `->bind_param()` method.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't address the original issue. Please read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35366163/5517143). By the way I'm not the one who downvoted this answer.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I think, now my answer near to real answer. Actually what he want, he want to set no of column dynamic, he can do it using php also.